# Laravel Sessions

Tags: laravel, session

Based on this [docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session)

Is it possible to store and retrieve data from sessions without using the `Schema`? For example, when I store a data into a `session`, will it generate the `key` and `value` in realtime?

**UPDATE:** It worked, I'm note sure why it didn't work at first. Here's what I did:

Storing

```
$request->session()->put('period', $request->period);
```

Retrieving

```
$period = $request->session()->get('period', 'default');
```

Comment: The `Schema` is only required once (typically in a migration), and only if you're using database-driven sessions. It sets up a database table for all your key/value pairs to be stored in. Individual keys/values are **not** part of the schema and don't have to be pre-defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

By Schema, i think you are referring to Database table for session. Which is only required if you are using `database` SESSION_DRIVER.

You can change your session driver in your .env file.

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Other session drivers include file, redis, memcache etc..

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to store and retrieve data from sessions without using the Schema? For example, when I store a data into a session, will it generate the key and value in realtime?

By default, Laravel stores sessions as files in the `storage` directory, so you don't need the `Schema` call in the documentation at all if you're using a stock config.

It's only required if you're using database-driven sessions, and it's a one-time setup - you'd typically put it in a database migration. Once your database is set up for sessions, you can store as many different session key/value pairs as you like without needing to run any additional Schema code.